# InvalidCastException Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .net

I'm developing a system that shows the total amount paid of a student from the database. For some students that only have a few transactions the function below gives an error `Conversion from string "" to type double...` but if a student doesn't have any data entry or the values are zero-to-many the code below encounters it. What should I do? Do I need to adjust the code? Please help.

I have here an Function that gets the total items.

```
Function Totalpaid() As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ((tbl_receipt.Items.Count) - 1)
        Totalpaid = (Totalpaid + tbl_receipt.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Also learn about [Implicit and Explicit Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kca3w8x6.aspx).  Right now your code is implicitly converting from a `String` to a `Double`, but it can't implicitly convert an empty string.

Comment: @Tim, the issue has nothing to do with `Option Explicit` because there are no implicitly declared variables in that code.  Presumably you meant `Option Strict`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx

Comment: @jmcilhinney - Yes, you are correct, I meant Option Strict.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add two numbers but one of the operands is not a number.  You're assuming that the `Text` of the subitem will be converted a number and added to the running total.  At least one of your subitems is blank though.  Maybe you consider that to represent zero but it doesn't.  It doesn't represent any number at all so the operation fails.

What you should be doing is validating and converting the subitem contents yourself and then providing the system with two `Double` values to add.  If there is no value then you either ignore that subitem or use zero explicitly.  `Option Strict On` will at least force you to perform the conversion but it's still up to you to provide the validation if there's any chance that the data will not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a problem with your data rather than the code directly. I would recommend sanitising your data before trying to use it in a calculation, i.e.:

```
Function Totalpaid() As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim val as Double
    For i = 0 To ((tbl_receipt.Items.Count) - 1)
        If Double.TryParse(tbl_receipt.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text, val) Then
             Totalpaid = (Totalpaid + val)
        End If
    Next
    Return Totalpaid
End Function
```

The message `Conversion from string "" to type double...` is saying that your are trying to convert an empty string to a `Double` which cannot work.

As a side note, when testing your code I did have to include the line `Return Totalpaid`, I don't know if this was missed when you where writing out the question.